# Design solution to varargin in C#

Tags: c#, matlab, oop, design-patterns

Matlab has a feature, `varargin` (https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/varargin.html), that allows for:

- Variable input argument list
- Text, value pairs
- Parsing of the value pairs into a structure

I have been using this feature to set parameters, such as:

- Choosing to provide verbose output (similar to logging)
- Open graphics windows to describe the results of a computation (sort of like graphics logging)
- Set parameters such as thresholds, search ranges, polynomial order for fitting, methods of interpolation (e.g. cubic spline, nearest neighbor).

**Matlab Example**

The example illustrates how the `inputParser` creates a structure that contains information from the argument list.  It enables default values and checking of the type of the input without specifying the order (or all) of the arguments

*The call to the method*

```
            obj.setRegionPeak('NumberMax', 5, 'IsVerbose', false)
```

*Method*

```
        function setRegionPeak = findPeaks(obj, varargin)
            p = inputParser;
            addParameter(p, 'NumberMax', 5);
            addParameter(p, 'WidthSearch', 6);
            addParameter(p, 'IsVerbose', 6);
            parse(p, varargin{:});

            if(p.Results.IsVerbose)
              % plot a figure
              % write to the console
            end

            while( (vMax > vPeakLowest) && (iFound < p.Results.NumberMax))
              % search for the bright spots
            end
```

A quick search on *StackExchange* for a similar feature in C# results in a number of opinions that perhaps this is not a good coding style or design.

Given a class with methods that I want to control parameters / features for computation and execution, what is the appropriate design that implements this functionality?

Seems to me, the intuitive answer is to have a property for each of the parameters, with values set by default in the constructor.  Then, call property setting methods to sets these properties before calling the method.

The `varargin` offers a convenient way to do this without having to create properties for every single parameter.

Is `varargin` a good approach or will it result in unmanageable code / design?

Comment: Have you looked at the `params` keyword? `params` will help if you have a variable number of inputs of the same type. If you're looking at different types of inputs, you want method overloading.

Comment: Interesting.  Perhaps this is a good choice.  I like the `varargin` because it creates a structure whose elements match the text used to describe the parameter.  You can put the arguments in any order and they can have any type.  I'm concerned less about whether or not the feature exists and am more concerned that it is a poor design practice.  Method overloading requires a specific ordering of the arguments, which removes some of the flexibility in `varargin`

Comment: As a counter to the point about method overloading, you can pass arguments in any order if you provide the name.  Anyway, your question is too broad because you haven't shown (only told) what kinds of inputs you expect to provide. There are many techniques you could mix and match but to get any real advice -- *and you should get more advice and not just settle with what you have now* -- the community needs to know where you're going with it. They may not know matlab so some example C# classes and code will go a ***long*** way.